# Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, python-2.7

I'm getting the below error while i'm calling my function,Does anyone have any suggestions on how to deal with it?
I want to insert the selected data into the destination table with the insert command.

> Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL tuple indices must be
>   integers or slices, not str

Sub function

```
def psql_func(msql, psql, msql_command, psql_command):
    print("function call")
    msql.execute(msql_command)

    for row in msql:
        try:
            psql.execute(psql_command, row)
        except psycopg2.Error as e:
            print ("Cannot execute the query!!", e.pgerror)

            sys.exit("Some problem occured with the query!!!")
```

The main function

```
commands = [("SELECT customer_id, entity_id, store_id, customer_email , customer_firstname, customer_middlename, customer_lastname , customer_is_guest, customer_group_id, created_at, updated_at, is_active, items_count, items_qty, base_currency_code, grand_total, base_to_global_rate, base_subtotal, base_subtotal_with_discount from clone.sales_flat_quote where is_active=1 AND items_count != '0' AND updated_at > '2019-05-09 00:00:00';",
             "INSERT INTO staging.sales_flat_quote (customer_id, entity_id, store_id, customer_email , customer_firstname, customer_middlename, customer_lastname , customer_is_guest, customer_group_id, created_at, updated_at, is_active, items_count, items_qty, base_currency_code, grand_total, base_to_global_rate, base_subtotal, base_subtotal_with_discount) \
              VALUES (%(customer_id)s, %(entity_id)s, %(store_id)s,%(customer_email)s,%(customer_firstname)s,%(customer_firstname)s,%(customer_middlename)s,%(customer_lastname)s,%(customer_is_guest)s, %(customer_group_id)s, %(created_at)s, %(updated_at)s, %(is_active)s, %(items_count)s, %(items_qty)s, %(base_currency_code)s, %(grand_total)s, %(base_to_global_rate)s, %(base_subtotal)s, %(base_subtotal_with_discount)s)"),

            ("SELECT store_id,row_total,updated_at,qty,sku,free_shipping,quote_id,price,no_discount,item_id,product_type,base_tax_amount,product_id,name,created_at from clone.sales_flat_quote_item WHERE updated_at > '2019-05-09 00:00:00'",
             "INSERT INTO staging.sales_flat_quote_item (store_id,row_total,updated_at,qty,sku,free_shipping,quote_id,price,no_discount,item_id,product_type,base_tax_amount,product_id,name,created_at) VALUES (%(store_id)s, %(row_total)s, %(updated_at)s, %(qty)s, %(sku)s, %(free_shipping)s, %(quote_id)s, %(price)s, %(no_discount)s, %(item_id)s, %(product_type)s, %(base_tax_amount)s, %(product_id)s, %(name)s, %(created_at)s)")]

   for msql_command, psql_command in commands:

       psql_func(cur_msql, cur_psql, msql_command, psql_command)
```

Comment: Can anyone suggest on this?

Comment: Most likely the rows produced by your mysql driver don't support access by key, only by index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substituted the insert command in the commands list as below, which solved my proble.

> """INSERT INTO staging.sales_flat_quote_item
>   (store_id,row_total,updated_at,qty,sku,free_shipping,quote_id
>                                                             ,price,no_discount
>   ,item_id,product_type,base_tax_amount,product_id,name
>                                                             ,created_at)
>                   SELECT %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s;"""